# How to set Chromium's window size via terminal?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I start a chromium windows via

```
chromium --new-window http://google.com
```

**How to force it to open with given dimensions, such as width 800px, heigh 600px ?**

---

I did try `chromium-browser --new-window --window-size=300,500`, `chromium-browser http://google.com --new-window --app-shell-host-window-size=400x400 --ash-host-window-bounds=100+200-600x300` and variants without success.

Comment: Is the awnser ok?

Answer (score 13):

Try with:

```
chromium-browser --window-size=800,600 https://www.google.com
```

Also can set the property `--window-position=0,0` for example, opens browser in the upper right corner.

Comment: --window-size=5000,5000  "makes all screens full screen :D"

Comment: At time of writing the `--window-position` arg seemingly does nothing on my Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.3 system.  Did it get changed to something, or something?

Comment: Same on Ubuntu, `--window-position` doesn't have any affect

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Setting window size and position did not work for me at first as well,
but putting values in quotes worked:

```
 --window-size="300,500" --window-position="300,500"
```

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Not working for me, Ubuntu 22.10 Chrome 109 :( :)